# PHP Search By Image Google cURL return 302 moved

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-302, google-image-search

I'm trying to get a simple string with the description of the image I searched with [search-by-image](https://github.com/hbattat/search-by-image). So I set up my search_by_google.php page:

```
    <?php
$url = $_REQUEST['url'];

if(empty($_REQUEST['raw'])){
$raw = false;
}
else{
$raw = true;
}
echo fetch_google($url, $raw);

function fetch_google($u, $raw, $terms="sample search",$numpages=1,$user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0')
{

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi';
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com/');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,120);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,10);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"./cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"./cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
    curl_exec($ch);

$searched="";
for($i=0;$i<=$numpages;$i++)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url="http://www.google.com/searchbyimage?hl=en&image_url=".urlencode($u);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,120);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,10);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"cookie.txt");
    $searched=$searched.curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
}
if($raw){
        return $searched;
    }
    else{
        $matches = array();
        preg_match('/Best guess for this image:[^<]+<a[^>]+>([^<]+)/', $searched, $matches);
        return (count($matches) > 1 ? $matches[1] : false);
    }
 }
  ?>
```

I've changed all the curl options but if I go to http://www.mysite.altervista.org/search_by_google.php?url=http://www.mysite.org/asdasd.jpg&raw=false

It keep me saying 302 Moved

[image]

I have changed my code putting

```
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
```

in the second curl_init() and now it gives me this message:

[image]

***EDIT 25/03/2014 19:34***

I changed my code like Sabuj Hassan said and the log now is:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found Cache-Control: public, max-age=21600 Date: Tue, 25 Mar 2014 18:30:07 GMT Age: 16 Location: http://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZisAo2ZcfY19aFUJcEj26M4zKc9ZuxzfsUPzLuUJk-pd-siPwiplqIcGN5tW1XPU16-XFg1EoK7jc5IU3BKoEHYnwZo7RmuhyF5p9qaZwSgq4FKRkNW44JgzTi4Mr8g6ezNMQ6YzaAEQ-uFbPMNzY40NrE3uB7ePm4BGNowF34PiIjLOiVLkWwQ7sRoBVMoVgzBbAP7rDwHee5LyGF8Dq6QOT1TEhsURduPD6exzITyRl77agELdpTFSi-JXDncI6c4KdcuQYSx2LknnIW6nippmpPf3X5OYGn1CFZw13rlFPitLSY0Ang0COuSXKdpBy6B8Dak9QZNZ9VFB4HBRfnMFiyuBvQtyhAg2LeOnRbjnunGB0P1RlwKBF4hRId7wUdTu4Dfab5DQu9hGauLKcd7GcP4g-jQXx_1gymwDdZnPXLzZp1mkjVMX9GFSppj-IRWp3FVVqChsPEzKXdraevuWJFukjUdF87dU_1kLKO23lC8L3kusy05zcq7ZxyF1dHNfQ0vYJeWumtbRosJNuEcqiSyVW_1-bF104HMJLdCA0gr5VyIZolkcZok4W1sgjFYTWvfj6f0proaGE24HSO4Ov2hmhAy9HQUCr3e-KjgqyP4AOtlmI3VsuLu34jKSo0t4tWbb5PVBi1_1oebuv4oisdVdw22a6CRH2tiw8wg6Ya1VgxsXhyj8U7lrQ8cBHVDKlOI6EimXtnELBHyDNQT1Zpsz1hK10GYvFaRNMFd7Rqmg87CLdycgyRV-sYxNWxIu9agNgHTwuU1W-GgeWWcM9noeMwgqMKSGh9lt_1hda3ZWrcA4Y1MeiG55b4ZYvOjcm9t9iIy6LA2S4AjC2X1qZHvJtSqzgfOz8yTuX5jUHqCl0jI1FdOSmqZV1GqQ0uaJfsuchlsWUULfUJBzFiGkAuOqIzU0bpXLNqLHoYPJUPwr66H6jWPFLsWAS9_1GRNj70s30jfbzcS0NUShUvE2meUhlpx-f5M0nmS0zvf-3OQOUkXlYO2VUZ4x9y8G76hHoTkDxqzhhGrgohyFmkUvAWmSkHTBpbP6gek8cyrmBnXuedSV3r2O71G8CUbdHFxfIO8FWlkGj1cUYu60PoKF6hndjZsOlV-dSNXfOTKeC1jPtf5ycXA0s0xLK7_1K0iWxhfmVq62WgQ4O3Prc4b6bcJm8M1Q9xZhhsElisuUyVTN9-dDMNUZ1h0tUe9oGsZYLh9vjEsMokqBXFM_1igHOfgRn4I17Xt8EBMZI9cEjakByjv-g5Pt9tG69RQm765HLhf8VpafvE5Z3BwDpZs4x5uMkVDURT9qcA&hl=en Server: quimby_frontend Content-Length: 1566 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Expires: Wed, 26 Mar 2014 00:30:07 GMT Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
302 Moved

The document has moved here. HTTP/1.0 302 Found Cache-Control: public, max-age=21600 Date: Tue, 25 Mar 2014 18:30:07 GMT Age: 16 Location: http://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZisAo2ZcfY19aFUJcEj26M4zKc9ZuxzfsUPzLuUJk-pd-siPwiplqIcGN5tW1XPU16-XFg1EoK7jc5IU3BKoEHYnwZo7RmuhyF5p9qaZwSgq4FKRkNW44JgzTi4Mr8g6ezNMQ6YzaAEQ-uFbPMNzY40NrE3uB7ePm4BGNowF34PiIjLOiVLkWwQ7sRoBVMoVgzBbAP7rDwHee5LyGF8Dq6QOT1TEhsURduPD6exzITyRl77agELdpTFSi-JXDncI6c4KdcuQYSx2LknnIW6nippmpPf3X5OYGn1CFZw13rlFPitLSY0Ang0COuSXKdpBy6B8Dak9QZNZ9VFB4HBRfnMFiyuBvQtyhAg2LeOnRbjnunGB0P1RlwKBF4hRId7wUdTu4Dfab5DQu9hGauLKcd7GcP4g-jQXx_1gymwDdZnPXLzZp1mkjVMX9GFSppj-IRWp3FVVqChsPEzKXdraevuWJFukjUdF87dU_1kLKO23lC8L3kusy05zcq7ZxyF1dHNfQ0vYJeWumtbRosJNuEcqiSyVW_1-bF104HMJLdCA0gr5VyIZolkcZok4W1sgjFYTWvfj6f0proaGE24HSO4Ov2hmhAy9HQUCr3e-KjgqyP4AOtlmI3VsuLu34jKSo0t4tWbb5PVBi1_1oebuv4oisdVdw22a6CRH2tiw8wg6Ya1VgxsXhyj8U7lrQ8cBHVDKlOI6EimXtnELBHyDNQT1Zpsz1hK10GYvFaRNMFd7Rqmg87CLdycgyRV-sYxNWxIu9agNgHTwuU1W-GgeWWcM9noeMwgqMKSGh9lt_1hda3ZWrcA4Y1MeiG55b4ZYvOjcm9t9iIy6LA2S4AjC2X1qZHvJtSqzgfOz8yTuX5jUHqCl0jI1FdOSmqZV1GqQ0uaJfsuchlsWUULfUJBzFiGkAuOqIzU0bpXLNqLHoYPJUPwr66H6jWPFLsWAS9_1GRNj70s30jfbzcS0NUShUvE2meUhlpx-f5M0nmS0zvf-3OQOUkXlYO2VUZ4x9y8G76hHoTkDxqzhhGrgohyFmkUvAWmSkHTBpbP6gek8cyrmBnXuedSV3r2O71G8CUbdHFxfIO8FWlkGj1cUYu60PoKF6hndjZsOlV-dSNXfOTKeC1jPtf5ycXA0s0xLK7_1K0iWxhfmVq62WgQ4O3Prc4b6bcJm8M1Q9xZhhsElisuUyVTN9-dDMNUZ1h0tUe9oGsZYLh9vjEsMokqBXFM_1igHOfgRn4I17Xt8EBMZI9cEjakByjv-g5Pt9tG69RQm765HLhf8VpafvE5Z3BwDpZs4x5uMkVDURT9qcA&hl=en Server: quimby_frontend Content-Length: 1566 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Expires: Wed, 26 Mar 2014 00:30:07 GMT Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
302 Moved

The document has moved here.
```

Comment: Could you check if this works locally? If you run this from localhost or php-cli? It seems to be working for me. Could be a config issue with your host.

Comment: Ah. Probably. I have a s***y host so it's probable

Comment: I've checked and my host support CURL (and also I have used it in another project) could you give me the url of your page ?

Comment: I just tested locally on my terminal using php-cli.

Comment: See my edit.. The error changed

Comment: It's not an error of my host becouse also the developer says that: "you have to get the CURL Options right to be able to get the result page, otherwise google does this weird protection thing where you will get 302 error (Page moved)"

Comment: @SmileApplications Run the curl with `curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);`, and update your question with that debug msg. And let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can happen that following redirection is blocked for your curl at your server. So I'll recommend you to handle the redirection manually. Like this one:

First your curl function. You can add other curl options if you like:

```
function curl($url, $user_agent, $retry=0){
    if($retry > 5){
        print "Maximum 5 retries are done, skipping!\n";
        return "in loop!";
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com/');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"./cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"./cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // handling the follow redirect
    if(preg_match("|Location: (https?://\S+)|", $result, $m)){
        print "Manually doing follow redirect!\n$m[1]\n";
        return curl($m[1], $user_agent, $retry + 1);
    }

    // add another condition here if the location is like Location: /home/products/index.php

    return $result;
}
```

And here is how it should be called:

```
$response = curl("http://www.google.com/", "Mozilla 5.0");
print "$response\n";
```

I am parsing the follow link from the `Location:` header. It can happen that the link is not started with `http://` That case add another condition over there.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is probably with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION which is unavailable if safe_mode or open_basedir are enabled in php.ini

Try this answer: http://au.php.net/manual/ro/function.curl-setopt.php#71313

Just replace curl_exec() with curl_redir_exec() provided in the comment.

Comment: In my case I wasn't add  `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);` to cur option array , now everything works .

Answer (score 4):

Check if you didn't hit max request per IP. You may be redirected to captcha page. AFAIK it is against google rules to use a robot to query google.